# Python equivalent of perl timestamp

Tags: python, perl, time

I have a function in perl:

```
sub print_ts {
    return ::strftime( '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S', localtime);
}
```

What would be python equivalent of that?

Comment: Where does `::strftime` come from?

Comment: @cuonglm, It's surely an alias to `POSIX::strftime`. As a whole, it returns the current local time in the specified format.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, I know `POSIX::strftime`, but not sure how can it be used like that, It confused me, why don't the OP use `return POSIX::strftime( ... )`?

Comment: @cuonglm, `::foo` is the same as `main::foo`. Simply using `use POSIX;` from the main namespace will create `::strftime`.

Comment: @ikegami: ... And also any user defined function in main namespace, too. And which one defined last will overwrite the other. Just want to notice the OP what confusion this code can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would be the equivalent in python:

```
from datetime import datetime

def print_ts():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: then just supply time.time() to the function?

Comment: or does python have localtime built-in?

Comment: python has a class called `datetime`. You can do`datetime.now()` to get current time. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

def print_ts():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```